# Detect 404 on video blob:https source

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, webrtc

I am using blob:https as source for my video-tags, like this:

```
function mk_bloburl(source_id, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob'; //important
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var blob = this.response;
            var source = document.getElementById(source_id);
            var video = source;
            if (video.tagName=="SOURCE") {
                video = source.parentNode;
            }
            video.oncanplaythrough = function() {
                URL.revokeObjectURL(source.src);
            };
            source.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            video.load();
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

mk_bloburl('review-video-source', my_video_url );
```

Having HTML like this:

```
<video id="review-video" controls="" width="100%">
    <source id="review-video-source" />
</video>
```

Now if I reload the page and start playing, it works. If I play and let it play through and then replay with no wait-time it works.
If I however reload the page and then wait for a while (like 1-2 minutes) and then press play, it fails.

Message I get in the Chrome browser looks like this:

```
GET blob:https://example.com/debeecfe-49b0-4c98-87d6-8ead325b2d75 404 (Not Found)
```

So, it's like the blob is auto-removed from the browser memory after a while. I want to catch the event when it is erased or when I get the 404 by starting the playback, so I can refresh the blob.

I have tried:

```
var source = document.querySelector("#review-video-source");
source.addEventListener("error", function(event) {
    console.debug("An error accoured");
});
```

But this does not seem to catch the error.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is caused by the fact you revoked the blobURI in the [`canplaythrough`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/canplaythrough) event.

The `canplaythrough` event is just a notice sent by the browser to let us know it thinks it will be able to load and play the whole media without interruption ; it doesn't mean that it has loaded everything yet.

In the case of BlobURI, the connection speed is so fast (it comes from memory) that the browser could think it is able to fetch the StarWars saga in 4k in a blink.
So you get this `canplaythrough` event really early, but the browser didn't actually uncompressed all the data yet. Still, you revoke the BlobURI, and when the browser tries again to fetch data so it can uncompress and read it, there is nothing anymore at the end of the BlobURI's pointer.

So for your problem, you've got two solutions :

- In case you need to play the media **only once** :
  call `URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURI)` in the [`ended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended) event. This will fire, the first time the currentTime of the video will reach the end.
- If you need to play the video **multiple times** :
  revoke the blobURI in the [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) event of the page. This way, your BlobURI pointer is always active for as long as the page is alive, but will not block the whole Blob in memory for longer than the page life (which would happen if you don't revoke the BlobURI at all).

---

And about how to *Detect 404 on video blob:https source*, I don't really know a good way, except listening for an unexpected jump to the end, but this should not be needed for blobURIs anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around it is using the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) like so :

```
function mk_bloburl(source_id, url){
  fetch(url)//usual get
  .then(response=>{
    if(response.status == 404)
    //Should set here what is an error (ex: x>299)
      Promise.reject("Error 404!");
    return response.blob();
  })//get blob
  .then(blobObj=>{//use blob
    var blob = blobObj;
    var source = focument.getElementById(source_id);
    var video = source;
    if(video.tagName === "SOURCE")
      video = source.parentNode;
    video.oncanplaythrough = ()=>{
      URL.revokeObjectUrl(source.src);
    };
    source.src = URL.revokeObjectURL(blob);
    video.load();
  })
  .catch(error=>{
    //There has been an error,
    //do something about it
    //here
  });
}
```